# Renaming datasets in environment

Tags: r, rename, environment

Here's what is in my environment. I have a bunch of csv files loaded as data frames ,named by some combination of Month/Year, in my environment.

[image]

What I would like to do is rename these objects, not the columns/rows, but the objects themselves.

For example, I am interested in removing the "FRL.csv", or last 7 characters of the character string that titles each of these data frames. Then I would get "APR03", "APR04", ..... , "JUL02", "JUL03".

**What I've done.**

Here's how to acquire the list of names that are the labels of the objects in my environment.

```
ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv)

[1] "APR01FRL.csv" "APR02FRL.csv" "APR03FRL.csv" "APR04FRL.csv" "APR05FRL.csv" "APR06FRL.csv" "APR07FRL.csv"
[8] "APR08FRL.csv" "APR09FRL.csv" "JAN01FRL.csv" "JAN02FRL.csv" "JAN03FRL.csv" "JAN04FRL.csv" "JAN05FRL.csv"
[15] "JAN06FRL.csv" "JAN07FRL.csv" "JAN08FRL.csv" "JAN09FRL.csv" "JAN10FRL.csv" "JUL01FRL.csv" "JUL02FRL.csv"
[22] "JUL03FRL.csv" "JUL04FRL.csv" "JUL05FRL.csv" "JUL06FRL.csv" "JUL07FRL.csv" "JUL08FRL.csv" "JUL09FRL.csv"
[29] "JUL10FRL.csv" "MAR10FRL.csv" "MAY10FRL.csv" "NOV09FRL.csv" "NOV10FRL.csv" "OCT01FRL.csv" "OCT02FRL.csv"
[36] "OCT03FRL.csv" "OCT04FRL.csv" "OCT05FRL.csv" "OCT06FRL.csv" "OCT07FRL.csv" "OCT08FRL.csv" "SEP09FRL.csv"
[43] "SEP10FRL.csv"



assign(
   ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
   paste(
     substr(ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), 1, 3), 
     substr(ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), 4, 5), 
           sep = "-")
   )
```

Which is just me attempting to assign new strings to replace those in the global environment.

Inside the paste code are strings that I am inputting.

```
paste(
         substr(ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), 1, 3), 
         substr(ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), 4, 5), 
               sep = "-")

[1] "APR-01" "APR-02" "APR-03" "APR-04" "APR-05" "APR-06" "APR-07" "APR-08" "APR-09" "JAN-01" "JAN-02" "JAN-03"
[14] "JAN-04" "JAN-05" "JAN-06" "JAN-07" "JAN-08" "JAN-09" "JAN-10" "JUL-01" "JUL-02" "JUL-03" "JUL-04" "JUL-05" "JUL-06"
[27] "JUL-07" "JUL-08" "JUL-09" "JUL-10" "MAR-10" "MAY-10" "NOV-09" "NOV-10" "OCT-01" "OCT-02" "OCT-03" "OCT-04" "OCT-05"
[40] "OCT-06" "OCT-07" "OCT-08" "SEP-09" "SEP-10"
```

I get this error when I run the assign code.

> Warning message: In assign(ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv),
>   paste(substr(ls(all.names = TRUE,  :   only the first element is used
>   as variable name

and none of the data sets in my environment are renamed.

[image]

**Does anyone have suggestions on how to go about renaming objects in the environment pane, or the objects themselves?**

Comment: Read them in as a list of data.frames.

Comment: @alistaire that's what i ended up doing using `mget(ls(pattern = ".csv"))` or something related, but the question still stands.

Comment: You're still trying to fix things after the fact instead of before. The pattern is something like `df_list <- lapply(list.files(pattern = '.csv'), function(f){df <- read.table(f); df$name <- sub('FRL.csv', '', f); df}); single_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)`

Comment: Nice preventative advice and I agree with this.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a simple for-loop:

```
## create test objects (because I don't have your data.frames)
ns <- c('APR01FRL.csv','APR02FRL.csv','APR03FRL.csv','APR04FRL.csv','APR05FRL.csv','APR06FRL.csv','APR07FRL.csv','APR08FRL.csv','APR09FRL.csv','JAN01FRL.csv','JAN02FRL.csv','JAN03FRL.csv','JAN04FRL.csv','JAN05FRL.csv','JAN06FRL.csv','JAN07FRL.csv','JAN08FRL.csv','JAN09FRL.csv','JAN10FRL.csv','JUL01FRL.csv','JUL02FRL.csv','JUL03FRL.csv','JUL04FRL.csv','JUL05FRL.csv','JUL06FRL.csv','JUL07FRL.csv','JUL08FRL.csv','JUL09FRL.csv','JUL10FRL.csv','MAR10FRL.csv','MAY10FRL.csv','NOV09FRL.csv','NOV10FRL.csv','OCT01FRL.csv','OCT02FRL.csv','OCT03FRL.csv','OCT04FRL.csv','OCT05FRL.csv','OCT06FRL.csv','OCT07FRL.csv','OCT08FRL.csv','SEP09FRL.csv','SEP10FRL.csv');
for (n in ns) assign(n,data.frame());

## retrieve all target data.frames by name pattern
ns <- ls(all.names=T,envir=globalenv(),pattern='FRL\\.csv$');
ns;
## [1] "APR01FRL.csv" "APR02FRL.csv" "APR03FRL.csv" "APR04FRL.csv" "APR05FRL.csv" "APR06FRL.csv" "APR07FRL.csv" "APR08FRL.csv" "APR09FRL.csv" "JAN01FRL.csv" "JAN02FRL.csv" "JAN03FRL.csv" "JAN04FRL.csv" "JAN05FRL.csv" "JAN06FRL.csv" "JAN07FRL.csv" "JAN08FRL.csv" "JAN09FRL.csv" "JAN10FRL.csv" "JUL01FRL.csv" "JUL02FRL.csv" "JUL03FRL.csv" "JUL04FRL.csv" "JUL05FRL.csv" "JUL06FRL.csv" "JUL07FRL.csv" "JUL08FRL.csv" "JUL09FRL.csv" "JUL10FRL.csv" "MAR10FRL.csv" "MAY10FRL.csv" "NOV09FRL.csv" "NOV10FRL.csv" "OCT01FRL.csv" "OCT02FRL.csv" "OCT03FRL.csv" "OCT04FRL.csv" "OCT05FRL.csv" "OCT06FRL.csv" "OCT07FRL.csv" "OCT08FRL.csv" "SEP09FRL.csv" "SEP10FRL.csv"

## rename them with a for-loop
for (n in ns) { n2 <- sub('FRL\\.csv$','',n); assign(n2,get(n)); rm(list=n); };

## show the result
ls(all.names=T,envir=globalenv(),pattern='FRL\\.csv$');
## character(0)
ls(all.names=T,envir=globalenv(),pattern='^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$');
## [1] "APR01" "APR02" "APR03" "APR04" "APR05" "APR06" "APR07" "APR08" "APR09" "JAN01" "JAN02" "JAN03" "JAN04" "JAN05" "JAN06" "JAN07" "JAN08" "JAN09" "JAN10" "JUL01" "JUL02" "JUL03" "JUL04" "JUL05" "JUL06" "JUL07" "JUL08" "JUL09" "JUL10" "MAR10" "MAY10" "NOV09" "NOV10" "OCT01" "OCT02" "OCT03" "OCT04" "OCT05" "OCT06" "OCT07" "OCT08" "SEP09" "SEP10"
```

Comment: So there's no simple way to edit the names other than re-create them in the environment? Both of the answers here are okay, but it seems strange that we can't rename objects in the environment without overriding the objects entirely.

Comment: Your override is using this statement: `for (n in ns) { n2 <- sub('FRL\\.csv$','',n); assign(n2,get(n)); rm(list=n); };`

Comment: Hi there, for any reason, the data frames are getting duplicated. The rm part is not working. Any explanation for that?

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop with an `assign` and a `rm` in it can be used to do this. You may need to add a `pattern` argument to `ls` in order to avoid renaming object you don't want to rename.

```
APR01FRL.csv <- 1
JAN06FRL.csv <- 2
JUL03FRL.csv <- 3

(function(){
  for (old_name in ls(pos = .GlobalEnv)){
    new_name <- paste(
      substr(old_name, 1, 3), 
      substr(old_name, 4, 5), 
      sep = "-")
    assign(x = new_name, value = get(old_name, pos = .GlobalEnv), pos = .GlobalEnv)
    rm(list = old_name, pos = .GlobalEnv)
  }
})()

print(data.frame(name = ls(), value = get(ls())))
```

Comment: So there's no simple way to edit the names other than re-create them in the environment? Both of the answers here are okay, but it seems strange that we can't rename objects in the environment without overriding the objects entirely. The recreating of objects is here, no?
 `assign(x = new_name, value = get(old_name, pos = .GlobalEnv), pos = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: When you say "override" I assume you're referring to the fact that we are making an assignment to the new name of the variable. I'm unaware of any other way that a language could do this (caveat: this is not my wheelhouse). All languages I know of use a hash table to make associations between variable names and memory addresses. Creating a new binding means hashing the new name. R is memory efficient in that it does not copy values into new memory unless it has to. Taken together, I believe that means R is using the fastest possible algorithm to accomplish our goal here.