# Replace character in all dataframes in the environment

Tags: r

I am running a function that returns several datasets in the environment to me. However, these datasets all have a space in their name. Is there a way to replace the space in each dataframe in the global environment with another symbol? I will have 100 datasets in my global environment, so it would be tedious to manually rename them all.
I have tried to come up with a solution using `assign` and `str_replace_all` but it hasn't worked so far.

MRE:

```
`Data frame` <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), y = sample(letters[1:24], 10, replace = T))
`Shame data` <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), y = sample(letters[1:24], 10, replace = T))
`Lambda dito` <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), y = sample(letters[1:24], 10, replace = T))
```

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752688/renaming-datasets-in-environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an adaptation of a recent [answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2021-November/473038.html) of mine to a [R-Help question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2021-November/473033.html). See also [Duncan Murdoch's answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2021-November/473034.html).
You can get all objects to be changed into a list, change the list's names attribute and assign back to the `.GlobalEnv`. Something like the following.

```
# create a vector of names of the objects
# whose names are to be changed
obj_names <- ls(pattern = " ")

# get the objects into a list
tmp_list <- mget(obj_names, envir = .GlobalEnv)
# change the list's names
names(tmp_list) <- sub(" +", "_", obj_names)
# assign them to the global environment
list2env(tmp_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)

# clean up
rm(tmp_list)
rm(list = obj_names)
```

Comment: This looks a bit safer than just editing the data.frames in the GlobalEnv, because it edits them inside a list, and only then assigns them back to the GlobalEnv. I think a different method may eventually lead to a dreadful outcome should anything go wrong...

Comment: @GuedesBF Yes, I believe that too. But Duncan Murdoch's advice in his answer to the R-Help question is still the best option. If the user has noticed the problem, correct the code that produced it, right?

Comment: Oh, Yes, Rui. I just read Duncann's answer and it is definitely the way to go. Not nearly as fancy as an answer, but the best advice ever. Why patch some bad code with additional code, when we can just make it cleaner from the start? It is a bit hard to get a working answer like that though, for SO, as the OP may have to share the entire script, and we do not want to change SO into a code review forum. Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `clean_names` function and apply it to all dataframes in the environment:

```
library(janitor) # for clean_names function

dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

lapply(dfs, clean_names)
```